# `sun.awt.FontConfiguration` error in openshift with `ubi8/openjdk-8-runtime` base image

Tags: docker, package, dockerfile, containers, openshift

I am using `ubi8/openjdk-8-runtime` base image to deploy a standalone java app which generates jasper reports in `openshift` environment. I am getting runtime error `java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)`. There are no package managers like `apk` or `apt-get` to install `ttf-dejavu`.

How to install `ttf-dejavu` package in my container using this base image? Or do you suggest a different base image ? I am allowed to get only certified base images from redhat registry OR quay.io

Answer (score 1):

Use a different base image that is better supported to run java applications on openshift. I changed the base image from `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-8-runtime` to `registry.redhat.io/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift` and that resolved the issue.